# CoInitialize() is undefined - Python error

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am learning multithreading in Python. I was going through examples online and trying out multithreading for my WMI module which remotely connects to the remote machine. But, when I use `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`, it gives me an error saying that `'CoInitialize is an undefined variable'`. I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What gives you the error?  Is it a runtime error, or a dev environment error?

Comment: its not a runtime error. Apparently, I am using Aptana IDE, and as soon as I use pythoncom.CoInitialize(), it throws me this error "Undefined variable from import:CoInitialize". But when I try the same through command prompt, it doesn't. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved. Pythoncom was included in my support libraries, but being a C extension my PyDev environment was not able to get the CoInitialize as a global variable. So I explicitly added CoInitialize through:

Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Analysis

Here, in the 'Undefined' tab (since CoInitialize was coming up as undefined error in PyDev) add CoInitialize (comma separated).

Now restart Aptana. Error is gone and everything works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the Aptana IDE not recognizing `CoInitialize` as it's a C extension, not a method defined in .py source.

PyDev allows you to customize which built-ins are loaded.  For details, see [Forced Builtins in the manual](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html).  Given that Aptana uses PyDev internally for Python support, you should be able to configure this to include `pythoncom` and eliminate this error.

Comment: I thought this could be the problem initially, but I have configured  python interpreter (python 2.7) in Aptana already.  Also I tried importing _ctypes (import _ctypes) in my project and it does not give me any error (assuming that's a C extension).

Comment: Addition: I am able to import pythoncom as well

Comment: @user2150258 That's separate from being able to import - that's what the IDE uses to parse the builtins...